# How to check the API version of Workbench in connected app?

Tags: connected-apps

I want to check the API version of Workbench in the connected app of Salesforce. I want to restrict users from using Workbench versions less than 50.0.

Comment: I think this question may be better phrased as "Can we restrict connected apps to certain API versions?". The answer is no, but I do think it is a fair question.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is not possible. Connected Apps don't have a way to detect the version of the client software. You could, however, [block the Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage.htm&type=5) for the Salesforce-hosted version, and [host your own version](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench) instead, using your own Connected App.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can Custom attributes be used for this? I used the $Api.Enterprise ServerUrl as a custom attribute, but that also didn't stop the users from using older version. Also, I checked the connectedappplugin apex class but that also didn't help. I used authorize method of the apex class to block the login but there is no method to get the API version of the client software.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm not really even sure of your use case here, actually. It'd help if you explained what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to keep people from using an older version of workbench, or just prevent them from using an older API?

Comment: I have to prevent the users from using older API. So, If an user is using API 47.0 then login for that user on workbench would fail.

Comment: @Abhishek Again, why is this a requirement? As stated here, this is really an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).